# Can Python decorators be used to return non-function objects?

Tags: python

In Python, can you write a decorator that returns a non-function object, like a string or a dictionary? For example, considering this code:

```
def decorator(function):
    return str(function)

@decorator
def foo(bar):
    return bar + 1
```

This code works, but is it an accepted practice within the community?

Comment: The first part of the question seems really easy to check for yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put the emphasis on the second part.

Comment: @delnan -- While I've used this comment in the past, we should be careful throwing it around.  Even if it *works*, that doesn't mean that it's defined behavior that is guaranteed to work across different python implementations.

Comment: @mgilson That is true, and I'm using the same objection whenever someone says "try it" in a C++ question. Python however has far fewer corners, most of the implementation defined behavior is either incredibly obscure or (the exception to the previous, but easy to identify) a direct consequence of refcounting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To quote PEP 0318:

> The current syntax for function decorators as implemented in Python 2.4a2 is:

```
@dec2
@dec1
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
```

> This is **equivalent** to:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
func = dec2(dec1(func))
```

> without the intermediate assignment to the variable func.

So, to answer your question, you **can** have a decorator return something which isn't a function and the behavior is completely defined.  Otherwise, it wouldn't be equivalent to the code above.

However, doing so would be terribly unclear.  People expect function decorators to return functions (or at least callable objects) and class decorators to return classes.  If you stray from that pattern, do so at your own risk -- If your neighbor decides to knock down your cubicle out of anger and frustration, that's your problem :).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I would claim that it's completely acceptable to return a non-function from a decorator. A *nonsensical* decorator is a problem, such as one that throws away the function (or most of it). A decorator that wraps the function in something else is not only useful, it's done even in the standard library: Many of the `functools` decorators return a custom callable object (which internally wraps the decorated function, of course).

Of course, there's also a point where using decorator syntax becomes misleading, because whatever is returned cannot reasonably be interpreted as stand-in for the decorated function. For example, I wouldn't use `dis.dis` as decorator although it would work. The problem with it is not that it doesn't return a function, or has a side effect (many useful decorators have side effects, such as "register this" decorators). The sole problem is that it leaves the function name bound to `None` rather than to something meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

There are some obscure uses for decorators that don't rely on returning a function. And, yes, to answer your direct question, it's completely legal, but, no, it's not common.

As an example, you can use them to immediately call a function.

```
def iifb(*args, **kwargs):
    def fn(f):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return fn

@iifb(1,2)
def hash(x, y):
    return x ^ y ^ (x << 3) ^ (y >> 1)

print(hash)   # prints 10
```

And, of course, classes are callable, so you could do the same thing to immediately instantiate a class.